# Generate clusters from a graph based on edges within cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis, networkx, graph-theory, networkit

Let's say we have an undirected and unweighted network graph.

What is the best algorithm to use to generate "clusters" that have the following properties:

- Within a given cluster, each node must have an edge to at least x other nodes in the cluster. For example, if we choose a value of x = 5, it means that each node in that cluster must have an edge to at least 5 of the other nodes in the cluster
- A node can belong to more than one "cluster". I'm not trying to determine "subgraphs". A node could be part of 20 clusters, so long as the cluster property above (eg. at least x edges to the other nodes in the cluster) is met.

Is there an algorithm that can be used to determine this?

Comment: Can you provide a constructor for an example graph?

Comment: @mozway - the graph will be constructed by a list of edges (eg. a-b, b-c, a-c, a-d, etc). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LOOP N over nodes 
   IF N has less than X edges 
       Remove N and all its edges from graph
REPEAT until no more nodes can be removed.
```

You now have one or more clusters that meet the requirement.  Use a component finder algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms ) to identify the clusters.

Here is a typical result of running the algorithm on a graph with two clusters that meet your requirement.

Original graph.  The algorithm removes the red nodes and edges

[image]

Result - it is a graph with two components

[image]

Comment: So that helps get rid of nodes that don't have enough edges to be part of a cluster. But how do you determine the clusters from the remaining graph? Also, is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: Your question has no constraint on the clusters except the adjacency number.  So there is no meaningful way to split the clusters any further.

Comment: the number of clusters we can generate is not infinite. Are there any ways we can generate possible clusters?

Comment: I have posted the algorithm to generate clusters that meet your requirement.  Certainly the number will not be infinite, if the original graph is finite.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. The output of the algorithm above is a graph, not a list of clusters

Comment: A cluster is a graph.  If there are more than one cluster in the original graph then the output will be a graph with more than one component.

Comment: There are well known algorithms for listing the components of a graph.  Your graph library probably provides a method to do so.

Comment: but the components of that graph won't necessarily meet the condition above, namely that all the members of the component must have at least x edges to other nodes in that component.

Comment: Yes, they will.  I suspect you do not know what a graph component is.  Please read the article linked to in my answer.

Comment: But what if one of the red nodes had 5 edges, 3 to the subgraph on the left and 2 to the subgraph on the right? You wouldn't remove them, yet that's does not meet the criteria outlined

Comment: In that case you would have one cluster with 13 nodes.